# Should menu titles (h1, h2, h3...) be inside or outside the <nav> tag?

Tags: html, html5, semantic-web

Let's say I want to write a simple menu in HTML5.

Should I write like this:

```
<h1>My Menu</h1>
<h2>Submenu 1</h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
<h2>Submenu 2</h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Or like this:

```
<nav>
    <h1>My Menu</h1>
    <h2>Submenu 1</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <h2>Submenu 2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In other words, should the titles be inside or outside the `<nav>` tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the HTML5 spec, "nav" is a "section" and a section "is content that defines the scope of headings and footers." The W3C example for the nav section shows h tags in the the nav.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element

Comment: Agree with this. You can only have one `<h1>` per 'scope' so moving outside the nav would probably break this rule, and imply your page is titled 'My Menu'.

Comment: I found this nice reference the other day: http://simon.html5.org/html5-elements

Answer (score 2):

h tags are for the structure of the content of the page. I wouldn't say navigation is part of the content of the page, so it doesn't make sense to me to have h tags in the navigation.

Comment: That's partly true, and prior to the introduction of `nav`, I would never use a heading tag for navigation menus. However, navigation menus can contain headings, which the `h` tags are the only semantically correct way of representing. Putting it inside of `nav` lets the document parser know that it's not part of the official content.

Comment: Interesting. I still wouldn't advise putting the h1 tag in there though as it's the main heading for the page. Maybe h2.

Comment: Yes, you can use h tags for menus for example. I just didn't know if the h1 had to be inside or outside. See the link given by bogeymin: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element